# Redirect user to HomePage after buying

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

I am working with Reactjs in the UI and Java with Spring Boot in the Back End,

My question is, How can I redirect the user after buying a chocolate just for given an example to the HomePage if the user clicks on back button in the browser?
I´ve seen web pages like amazon and walmart doing this.
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Did the below answer not answer it correctly? (you reopened this question by unaccepting the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cient side you can do this using javascript:

```
window.location.replace("https://www.yourDomain.com");
```

Server side you can do the redirect by using the response object. See this article for more information on server redirecting in spring boot:

[A Guide To Spring Redirects](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward)